# Detect on which browser current web application is running

Tags: php

I wanted to know in PHP, how to detect on which browser my web application is running.

e.g.

If current browser is chrome then alert("Chrome browser processing") otherwise alert("rest browser processing");

```
echo $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
```

Below output I am getting If i execute above code :

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/532.0 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/3.0.195.21 Safari/532.0
```

Please suggest your pointers to detect exact browser name.

Thanks,

-Pravin

Comment: I'm not sure what you're planning on doing with this on the server side.  If you're just using it for logging, or gathering statistics or something, then all well and good, but (just in case) I'd advise you to avoid trying to serve up different content to different browsers.

Comment: I updated my answer with a PHP approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I'd use Javascript for this one.

```
if(navigator.userAgent.match(/Chrome/i)) {
    alert("You're using Chrome!");
}
else {
    alert("You're using something other than Chrome!");
}
```

... but if you really wanted to, you could accomplish the same thing in PHP:

```
if (preg_match("/Chrome/i", $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) == 0) {
    // zero matches
    echo "<script>alert('You're not using Chrome!')</script>";
} else {
    echo "<script>alert('You're using Chrome!')</script>";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply, actually I wanted to do this in php.

Comment: Updated for the same thing only in PHP.

Answer (score 2):

[This](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php) has some useful code.

Basically, in your case, you can just look for the string "Chrome". In general, it might take a bit more logic, since, for example, the string "Safari" is found in the user-agents provided by other browsers than Safari (including Chrome). PHP provides the 'browser' element for this.